# Magento 2 Filter product collection by only stock in products

Tags: magento2, product, collection, product-collection

In Magento 2 how can we get a collection of products with only products that are in stock. Please help

Answer (score 7):

**Magento 1**

This snippet provides a collection of in-stock products, or products which do not have stock management enabled on them.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```

**Magento 2**

Use below code to your class to filter out of stock product:

```
protected $_stockFilter;

 public function __construct(
      ....
      \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter
      ....
      ) 

      {
        $this->_stockFilter = $stockFilter; 
      }
```

in your method add the following code to add products that are in stock

```
public function getProducts() {

..........

 $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

..........

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using addInStockFilterToCollection available in the CatalogInventory module to add an InStock Filter to the collection. See example below.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```

Comment: How will we do the same in magento 2?

Comment: @chin , For Magento2 see Shahab's answer below

Comment: Question is for magento 2 not 1.x